# Embeded comment paging in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, paging, comments

if I got a collection for storing Articles with it's Comments embedded, when retriving data from db, I will get a Article object with a completely Comment list, support there are a lot of comments, so this could be a problem of loading efficience, how can I handler this by paging Comments? do I have to use a seperate collection for Comments? or what else? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You looking for the [$slice](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements) operator.

To retrieve comments by paging you need code like this:

```
db.articles.find({}, {comments:{$slice: [20, 10]}}) // skip 20, limit 10
```

This operation will return articles with only sliced comments. )

Answer (score 0):

The biggest question is:

**Are your users more interested in comments or in context viewed?**

**Highly:**
Put comments in separate documents, and load them **first!**
Then send "secondary" content via AJAX.

**Moderately:**
Use Andrew's solution. (And do not forget that you can also omit fields in queries)

**Hardly:**
Put comments in separate documents, and load them **last** (via AJAX).

(Also using AJAX can give you nice feature of expanding loaded comments via simple scrolling down)