# Implement embedded paging with total pages in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongodb-java

I've checked out [an older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512694/embeded-comment-paging-in-mongodb) that is related with my embedded paging situation. Although the embedded paging with slicing works fine, the *total pages* solution is still missing, and i wonder whether it's possible to get the total size of the comments on the server side.

Is there a way to query or count the size of the embedded array on the server without having to fetch the whole document to my app and count it manually ?

I dont mind making 2 queries for this, 1 for paging the comment, 1 for getting the total of the comments. If i can do this in one query, that'll be amazing though.

By the way, i am using the java driver and spring-data mongodb.

Please share your thoughts. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best/fastest way to get total count of embedded documents is create an additional field and recalculate count after each update/insert.
Document will be like this

```
{
  _id: 1,
  comments: [],
  commentsCount: 5
}
```

Then you can simply include `commentsCount` field when do slice:

```
//this query will include only 10 comments _id and comments count of root document
db.articles.find({}, {comments:{$slice: [20, 10]}, _id:1, commentsCount: 1})
```

And actually there is no other way to calculate total count of embedded documents (i am not talking about m/r, because it is slow for real time requests)

Comment: Your answer is like a headshot to me. I've been using denormalization and counting for many cases, but i didnt think of that for this case. Thank you !

Comment: @AlbertKam: Denormalization is a best friend of nosql database ;)